# Is it possible to convert a symbol to string of key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Changing a symbol to string in ruby

The following works

a = :'title of the book'

a = a.to_s

But while trying to change the key of hash, the above does not work.

Comment: Why do you want to change a key used in a hash?

Comment: What does 'not work' mean? Can you be more specific about error messages, etc. Or at least give a sample of the code that does NOT work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stringify_keys`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/stringify_keys) to change all of your hash's keys into strings.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I suggest: **Hash.stringify_keys**
This would convert {:Key => value} to {"Key" => value}